# Undefined reference to 'Myclass::i' error in c++

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class Myclass {
    public:
    static int i;
    Myclass()
    {
        i=3;
        Fun();
    }
    void Fun()
    {

        i--;
        if(i>0)
            Fun();
        cout<<i;
        i++;
    }

};




int main()
{
    Myclass *p = new Myclass();

    return 0;
}
```

What's wrong with this?
undefined reference to `Myclass::i' errors occur.` But If I remove `Myclass *p = new Myclass();`, then the program executes. What should be the output of this? As there is a line as `static int i;` I suggest the output `000` Would anybody please explain?

Thanks in advance

Comment: In particular this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/12574407/3747990 for the static member variables.

Comment: add `int Myclass::i = 0;` before main() and read the links above :)